# How can we write "not equal" in c?

Tags: c, logical-operators, negation

In part of a code I saw this phrase:

```
!(word[i]==(tmpP->word[i]))
```

is it equal to

```
(word[i] != (tmpP->word[i]))
```

?

What is the difference between these two expressions?

Comment: Both versions are correct and are essentially the same. I would expect a compiler to produce the same result.

Comment: `(x != y)` == `!(x == y)`; where the not operator is just in a different spot / syntax.

Answer (score 2):

The expression

```
!(word[i]==(tmpP->word[i]))
```

is logically equivalent to the expression

```
(word[i] != (tmpP->word[i]))
```

Another example

```
!( a == b && c == d )
```

is equivalent to

```
!( a == b ) || !( c == d )
```

that is, in turn, equivalent to

```
a != b || c != d
```

Comment: Careful,  `!( a == b ) operator !( c == d )` is not the same as `a != b operator c != d`, when _operator_ is `+, -, *, /, >>, others` due to precedence differences.

Answer (score 2):

> what is the difference between these two expressions?

One can use `a != b` or `!(a == b)` interchangeably<sup>1</sup>.  Both use `a, b` once and both evaluate to an `int` of value 0 or 1.

Use the one most clear for the context of code (which is usually the first, but the seconds binds tighter.)

---

> How can we write "not equal" in c?

Standard C has *alternate spellings* macros in `<iso646.h>` (since C94) including `not_eq`.

```
and     &&
and_eq  &=
bitand  &
bitor   |
compl   ~
not     !
not_eq  !=
or      ||
or_eq   |=
xor     ^
xor_eq  ^=
```

Example

```
#include <iso646.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main() {
  srand((unsigned)time(0));
  int a = rand()%2;
  int b = rand()%2;
  if (a not_eq b) puts("Not equal.\n");
  else puts("Equal.\n");
}
```

Use `<iso646.h>` with caution as the macros may collide with existing code names.

---

<sup>1</sup> `!` has higher [precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) than `!=`, so with more complex expressions, be careful.  When in doubt, use an outer `()`: `(a != b)` versus `(!(a == b))` are truly the same.

Comment: The macros in `<iso646.h>` are reserved by the C Standard, so your native code should not be using them.

Comment: @Andrew True that code _should_ not be defining them, yet the impact of including `<iso646.h>` remains surprising for many with its `and, or, not`.  I do not see it as much of a problem with new code, but with the inclusion of various established user `"*.h"` files.